# Ajax success callback returns empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

A small application I'm working on is giving me a headache. I finally got it working to automatically complete one field with the same value that was entered in a different field. Now I'm trying to combine this with an AJAX request. Here's what the script should do.

When a certain words is entered in an input box, the input box next to this should automatically contain this word in a different language. I'm using a little PHP script for this which is not relevant to the problem I'm facing. The PHP script outputs the word 'bonjour'. When I enter the word 'hello', the input box next to where I entered should automatically autocomplete to 'bonjour' using an ajax request. It may be important to know that this input box is part of a form which contains thousands of input pairs. The part of autocompleting works, but when I try to combine this with the AJAX request, the success return data remains empty. Does anyone have an idea why this request data remains empty? I try to alert it when the first input value is changed.

```
var handleData = function (data) {
    alert(data);
}
var word = '';
$("table").on('change', '.master', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo site_url('wordsuggestion'); ?>/hello/english/french',
        type: 'GET',
        success : handleData
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 1000; //maximum input boxes allowed 
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID 

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<tr><td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="master" name="or['+x+']"></div></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="slave" name="tr['+x+']"></div></td></tr>'); //add input box
        }
    });
});
```

This would be the form that is used.

```
<form method="POST">
    <table width="100%" class="input_fields_wrap">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="master" name="or[0]"></div>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="slave" name="tr[0]"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Save</button>
</form>
<button class="add_field_button btn btn-default">Add more fields</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you verified that your server returns data with a success status code? Use the Network tab of Chrome Developer tools to spy on your HTTP requests, then see what comes back when you trigger your AJAX call.

Comment: @FredVollmer I worked with these requests before, and never had a problem. I can't find it in the network tab, tho.

Comment: "can't find it in the network tab". Then either you haven't looked in the correct place, or the ajax call is not happening. Are there any console errors? Does the `alert` in the handleData method pop up? Also normally if you are using the `.ajax` method you should handle the "error" callback so that you can track error responses and handle them in the UI.

Comment: @P.Yntema that sounds like the place to start debugging then. Looking at your code more closely, are you sure your `onChange` handler for the table ever fires? I don't think that table supports the onChange event. I would try to incorporate your AJAX request into the click handler for `add_button`

Comment: @ADyson I never work with Chrome, and don't need the network tab either so I may be looking wrong. That's the thing... you would say it would pop up empty but it doesn't even pop up.

Comment: (method: "GET", url: "test.html",  dataType: "html") check once the complete URL on console.

Comment: @Fred the onchange event is delegated to elements with the `master` class, which look to be textboxes. This will fire once the textbox loses focus.

Comment: @P.Yntema that suggests it either isn't running, or is returning an error. First add a console.log just before the line which runs .ajax(), to see if the event is actually triggering. If it is, then handle the "error" callback of the ajax call (see the jquery docs for details) and see if you get an error reported.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was a very simple (stupid) mistake, I'm just starting with JS. For some reason, the function needs to be wrapped by `$(function () {})`.

```
$(function () {
$("table").on('change', '.master', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo site_url('wordsuggestion'); ?>/hello/english/french',
            type: 'GET',
            success : handleData
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: actually you could have moved it inside your existing `"(document).ready(function() {` block. They are the same thing. It's telling the code to wait until all of the page is loaded before trying to run any script code - if you declare an event handler (like your change event) first on the page before any HTML elements are declared, then it will run, but not attach any events because at that moment there are no elements to attach it to. The "ready" wrapper means the code will wait until everything else is present before running. Now I feel a bit bad that I didn't spot that!

Comment: @ADyson No problem! Thanks, it seemed not logical but now it makes sense. Should I use this $function for every event handler?

Comment: yes it's quite sensible to wrap all handlers inside either(`$(function () {` or `$(document).ready(function() {` (they are exactly equivalent, one it just a shorthand for the other), then you know that the whole page will be loaded before the code tries to attach events.